# Disable DataTable css in Shiny/Flexdashboard

Tags: css, r, datatable, flexdashboard

I am constructing a `flexdashboard` app in `R`, but `DataTable` overwrites my custom css.

Is there a way I can pass an argument to `DataTable` in `Shiny` to disable  loading the DataTable css: `dt-core-1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css`? The problem is that `jquery` pushes in unwanted css in the html upon rendering the table, overwriting some of my custom written css

[image]

Comment: Are you using `includeCSS` to load your css?

Comment: @user5029763, yes, I am loading the css in the yaml header. The data table css is not present until I navigate to the page with the DT and then it pushes extra css into the html head